# Join table fields as a single JSON object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am building API. I ran into issue when building responses such as this one:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Some name",
    "my_joined_table": {
        "joined_table_id": "10",
        "some_joined_table_field": "some value"
    }
},
```

Joining tables as described in https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries would yield result such as:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Some name",
    "joined_table_id": "10",
    "some_joined_table_field": "some value"
},
```

Instead of using join I could just run two queries, one for main table, second one for secondary and then just append second array to first one and spit JSON response, but it's a lot of queries and appending if list is big!

Example code which yields second result in pseudo-code:

```
$data = Model::select('id', 'name', 'my_joined_table.id as joined_table_id', 'my_joined_table.some_value some_value')
->leftJoin('my_joined_table', function($join) { //conditions_callback 
})->get();
return response()->json($data);
```

Please advice.

EDIT2:

It seems that I can use `with` as follows:

```
$data = Model::with('my_second_table')->first();
return response()->json($data);
```

It does what I want,  only the problem, that I cannot specify fields for both first and second tables using `->first($fields)` and`->with(['my_second_table' => function ($query) { $query->select('id', 'some_value'); }])` unless I specify primary key of second table in `->first($fields)`. How do I work around this?

TL;DR; Issue: http://laravel.io/bin/YyVjd

Comment: Show your PHP code please, not just the resulting JSON.

Comment: I have added pseudo-code as requested, but it's nothing much, just standard stuff from laravel documentation I have posted link.

Comment: So - that code you posted outputs the JSON directly? How do you get from a sql result to a JSON string as output in your question?

Comment: Don't post links. The question should contain sufficient information. You need to make it as easy as possible for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use Laravel Eloquent relationship to achieve it.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Or you can remap the returned data to a new response object using $appends.
Try something here,
http://laraveldaily.com/why-use-appends-with-accessors-in-eloquent/

This is just some clues and there is a lots work to do.

FYI, you can set $visible in your model to specify which attributes is visible.